# Inserting images in SQLite database through a JSP form

Tags: sqlite, jsp

I have no idea why i chose to use SQLite database with my JSP project.
I was having problems configuring MySQL drivers on my Tiny Core Linux and even more problems when I ran my JSP project on my Windows using eclipse. On windows there were a lot of file permission issues.

So i chose to use SQLite on Tiny Core Linux instead. Making my Tiny Core Linux as a server on my Windows machine and used Port Forwarding through it to serve my project at localhost:9000.

Now the problem I have encountered is - 
"How do I insert an image in the DB through a JSP form ?"

I am using common file uploads jar file from commons.apache.org . When i used it on Windows and MySQL DB the code looked some like this :

```
if (servletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){

try {
 //DiskFileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();     
diskFileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(10 * 1024 * 1024); //10 MB
List items = null;
items = servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);
Iterator itr = items.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("inside while");
    FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        System.out.println("inside if");
        System.out.println("File Name = " + item.getFieldName() + ", Value = " + item.getString());
        if(item.getFieldName().equals("title")){
            title=item.getString();
        }
        // Getting other form field items.
    } else {
        System.out.println("inside else");
        System.out.println("Field Name = " + item.getFieldName()
                + ", File Name = " + item.getName()
                + ", Content type = " + item.getContentType()
                + ", File Size = " + item.getSize());
        File file = new File(repositoryPath, storename);
        item.write(file);
    }
}
out.println("File uploaded successfully");

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error from upload file report " + e);
}
try{
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, dbUserName, dbUserPassword);
    System.out.println("Connected to DB");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String strQuery = null;
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO movies (title, photo, description, seats, from, to, flag, timings) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(strQuery);
    statement.setString(1, title);
        //
          // Not able to figure out what to do for BLOB field - photo.
    //
        statement.setString(3, description);
    statement.setInt(4, seats);
    statement.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(format.parse(sd).getTime()));
    statement.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(format.parse(ed).getTime()));
    statement.setInt(7, display);
    statement.setString(8, timings);

    int row = statement.executeUpdate();
    if(row>0){
        message = "Movie added successfully";
        System.out.println(message);
    }   
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am uploading my file in enctype="multipart/formdata". 
The above code manages it very well.
All other conditions have already been set.

How do i the above code to use it on SQLite DB ?

**PS**:
*Variables url, dbName, dbUserName and dbUserPassword have been handled for SQLite.*

Comment: Could you please trim down your code to what is relevant to your question?

Comment: My recommendation: Try to insert an image into a SQLite database in a plain Java program. Only after this works, try to use Servelts or JSP as a frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data of the File, and use some sort of binary parameter/argument, such as setBytes or setBlob (although you will need to figure out how to instantiate a blob) or setBinaryStream, for the "photo" parameter. (Hint: FileInputStream would work great with setBinaryStream)

It's highly suggested, as the comments have said, that you do this on the servlet side of things (your "controller" if you are following a MVC pattern). JSP is meant mainly for presentation logic.